# Escuta de evento em uma lib

Tags: android, eventos

estou construindo uma lib mas no final do processo que ela realiza preciso que me avise que terminou, como posso implementar isso? alguma ideia?

No projeto que usa a lib faço assim:

```
Lib lib= new Lib (getActivity());      
lib.iniciaInteratividade();
```

Nesse iniciaInteratividade() é mostrado um Dialog e é feito todo um passo a passo, no final queria ser avisado de que terminou.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se quer escutar um evento, então crie um.

Uma forma simples de o fazer é definir uma interface que o objecto "ouvinte" deve implementar para ser notificado quando o evento ocorrer.

Comece pela interface, declarando-a na classe *Lib*:

```
public interface OnFinishListener{

    public void onFinish();
}
```

Se quiser passar alguma informação ao "ouvinte" declare parâmetros no método da interface(`onFinish()`)

Declare um método para indicar à classe *Lib* qual o ouvinte que deseja ser notificado:

```
//Atributo para guardar o "ouvinte"
private OnFinishListener listener;
public void setOnFinishListener(OnFinishListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

Quando quiser que a classe *Lib* notifique o "ouvinte" use:

```
if(listener != null){
    listener.onFinish();
}
```

Para usar faça assim:

```
Lib lib = new Lib (getActivity());
lib.setOnFinishListener(new OnFinishListener(){
    @Override
    public void onFinish(){

        //Coloque aqui o código a ser executado quando receber a notificação.
    }
});  
lib.iniciaInteratividade();
```

Comment: Bacana, funcionou certinho, obrigado Ramaral. :D

Comment: Se era isto que procurava considere em aceitar a resposta, clicando no V, no canto superior esquerdo dela.

Comment: Tinha clicado no ^ mas não no v , feito,obrigado novamente.

Answer (score 0):

Fala Marcelo,

Você pode criar uma váriavel boolean (na activity), e quando acabar o processo do Dialog você altera essa váriavel pra true.

Não resolve?

Abraços.

Comment: Buenas Leonardo, o amigo da resposta acima resolveu o problema.
Justamente o que precisava era captar o fim do processo do dialog (que fica lá dentro da lib) então precisava realmente de um listener.
Abraços.